# Saving a pandas dataframe into sqlite with different column names?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I have a a sqlite database and dataframe with different column names but they refer to the same thing. E.g.

1. My database Cars has the car Id, Name and Price.
2. My dataframe *df* has the car Identity, Value and Name.

Additional : I would also like to add an additional 'date' column in the database that is not there in the *df* and insert it based on the current date.

I would like to save the df in the database so that `Id = Identity`, `Price = Value`, `Name = Name` and `date = something specified by the user or current`

So I cannot to the usual `df.to_sql` (unless i rename the column names, but i wonder if there is a better way to do this)

I tried first to sync the names just without the date column `cur.execute("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(?,?,?)",df.to_records(index=False))`

*However, the above does not work and gives me an error that the binding is incorrect. Plus, the order of the columns in the DB and DF is different*

I'm not even sure how to handle the part where I have the extra date column, so any help would be great. Below is a sample code to generate all the values.

```
import sqlite3 as lite

con = lite.connect('test.db')

with con:

   cur = con.cursor()    
   cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Cars(Id INT, Name TEXT, Price INT, date TEXT)")
   df = pd.DataFrame({'Identity': range(5), 'Value': range(5,10), 'Name': range(10,15)})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

`cur.executemany("INSERT INTO Cars (Id, Name, Price) VALUES(?,?,?)", list(df.to_records(index=False)))`

Besides, you should specify the `dtype` attribute of your dataframe as `numpy.int32` to meet the constraint of table 'Cars'

```
con = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Cars(Id INT, Name TEXT, Price INT, date TEXT)")
df = pandas.DataFrame({'Identity': range(5), 'Value': range(5,10), 'Name': range(10,15)}, dtype=numpy.int32)

cur.executemany("INSERT INTO Cars (Id, Price, Name) VALUES(?,?,?)", list(df[['Identity', 'Value', 'Name']].to_records(index=False)))

query ="SELECT * from Cars"
cur.execute(query)
rows= cur.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print (row)
```

Comment: It works but on reading from it I get on reading it back:
 `(b'\x00\x00\x00\x00', b'\x05\x00\x00\x00', b'\n\x00\x00\x00', 'date')
(b'\x01\x00\x00\x00', b'\x06\x00\x00\x00', b'\x0b\x00\x00\x00', 'date')
(b'\x02\x00\x00\x00', b'\x07\x00\x00\x00', b'\x0c\x00\x00\x00', 'date')
(b'\x03\x00\x00\x00', b'\x08\x00\x00\x00', b'\r\x00\x00\x00', 'date')
(b'\x04\x00\x00\x00', b'\t\x00\x00\x00', b'\x0e\x00\x00\x00', 'date')`

Comment: these are ascii characters in hex. how did you store and read data from sqlite?

Comment: I just ran the above code on the dataframe i made in my question

Comment: then how did you read them? I tried `print cur.execute('select * from Cars').fetchall()` and got pretty values

Comment: @Chen  
 This is what I did `query ="SELECT * from Cars"
    cur.execute(query)
    rows= cur.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
         print (row)`

Comment: @CoderBC It should be ok. I ran your code and got expected data without problems. I add my code to the answer